# NotSupportedException on concat two IQueryable from same source

Tags: linq-to-sql

See the following code:

```
var source = Peoples.AsQueryable();
IQueryable<People> p;
p = source.Where( x => false);
p = p.Concat(source.Where( x => x.FirstName == "DAVID"));
p = p.Concat(source.Where(x => x.City_id == 3));
p.Dump(); //I use linqpad but it does not matter now
```

this code work, and linq2sql product one sql-statement (with three qouery and `UNION ALL`).

now the same code, ostensibly exactly the same procedure, in another variation, throw NotSupportedException:

```
var q = new IQueryableUnderstand<People>(Peoples.AsQueryable());
q.AddToList(x => x.City_id == 3);
q.AddToList(x => x.FirstName == "Dave");
q.Results().Dump();
```

IQueryableUnderstand Class:

```
class IQueryableUnderstand<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> _source;
    IQueryable<T> combin;

    public IQueryableUnderstand(IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        _source = source;
        combin = _source.Where(s => false);
    }

    public void AddToList(Func<T, bool> predicate) => combin = combin.Concat(_source.Where(predicate));

    public IQueryable<T> Results() => combin;
}
```

> LINQ To SQL exception: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains operator

I feel stupid, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AddToList()` method accepts a `Func<T, bool>` predicate.  The parameter type is incorrect.  If applied to your query, it will convert it to a Linq-To-Objects query. `IQueryable<TSource>` expects expressions, not delegates.

Change your method signature:

```
public void AddToList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) =>
    combin = combin.Concat(_source.Where(predicate));
```